# how can I use `find` to get the path from the starting point

Tags: linux, shell, find

I use conEmu to have som kind of linux terminal in windows.

In Windows I configured a variable to open files with sublime, and I can open files with:

```
$subl path/filename
```

I have a virtualMachine and I have the same code, in local and in the virtual host, but the paths are different:

```
D:\work (in win)
/home/work/ (in the server)
```

If I do:

```
$ ssh work@10.10.10.10 'find . -type f -name example.txt'
```

I get: `/home/work/public/example.txt`
But I can't use it to open with sublime:

```
subl $(ssh work@10.10.10.10 'find /home/work -type f -name example.txt') //doesn't work
```

So I need to have only the path from the starting point of /home/work, and have only `public/example.txt (or ./public/example)`

And This is the question, how can I use `find` to get the path from the starting point?

Comment: It sounds like you are just asking for `/home/work` to be stripped off? Or something more? Will Sublime understand `/` or does it need ``\`` in paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was "easy", using the `~` that marks the path to the home and then we only need to use `sed` to remove the text from the string.

```
find . -type f -name file | sed "s+$(echo ~)++"
```

`$(echo ~)` put the result of `echo ~` that is /home/work

And we need use the `"` instead of `'` to tell linux that they need to look for variables in the string

I use + instead of / (more usual) to evade the problem of the paths

```
sed 's//home/work//' cause problems
sed 's+/home/work++' doesn't
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you said `.` is ok, you could just cd to the directory first:

```
(cd somedir && find . [...])
```

With GNU find, you can also use the `%P` format specifier:

```
find somedir -printf '%P\n'  # \0 is safer if you can interpret nulls as delim
```

From `man find`:

> `%P`:     File's name with the name of the starting-point under which it was found removed.

Comment: It's only shows `example.txt`, and I need the `public/example.txt`